# Join 2 tables with all same column headers but one different

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

How do I join 2 tables that have all of the same column headers but one?

The other 3 columns are all the same then one table has the column header "January" and the other table has the column header "February"

So I would like to end up with 5 total columns in new table

I would also like all of the data in there even if there are duplicates.  Before I used a union all but now I cannot do that because not all my headers are the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION and rename one of your columns:

```
SELECT id, name, age, xxx FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id, name, age, yyy AS xxx FROM table2
```

If you add more information, I can elaborate my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select tb1.col1, tb1.col2, tb1.col3, tb2.col3 from tb1
inner join tb2 on (tb1.col1 = tb2.col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming uniqueness when just considering the three columns, joining them

```
SELECT tab1.col1, 
       tab1.col2, 
       tab1.col3, 
       tab1.january, 
       tab2.february 
FROM   tab1, 
       tab2 
WHERE  tab1.col1 = tab2.col1 
       AND tab1.col2 = tab2.col2 
       AND tab1.col3 = tab2.col3
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes all rows in tblA have corresponding ones in tblB and vice versa:

```
SELECT * FROM tblA INNER JOIN tblB USING (col1, col2, col3);
```

If that is not the case, and depending on the data (if `tbl1`.`january` can have legitimate null values, this won't work), you could try something like (*didn't check for sure, might need massaged with parenthesis, subselecting, etc...*):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 
LEFT JOIN tbl2 USING (col1, col2, col3)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl2 LEFT JOIN tbl1 USING (col1, col2, col3)
HAVING tbl1.`january` IS NULL
;
```